# Jade loop through object and assign childs to parents

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have a Object called "boards".

```
[{"id":1,"parent_board":0,"title":"Lorem 1","description":"ec40db959345153a9912"},
{"id":2,"parent_board":0,"title":"Lorem 2","description":"bb698136a211ebb1dfedb"},
{"id":3,"parent_board":1,"title":"Lorem 1-1","description":"6062bc28a9f781e06417d"}]
```

Now I want to loop through this object in Jade.

This is my current javascript function:

```
var htmlElem = document.getElementById('htmlElemId');
htmlElem.innerHTML = "";

for(var i = 0; i < boards.length; i++){
  if(boards[i].parent_board == 0){
    htmlElem.innerHTML += "<li id='" + boards[i].id + "'>" + boards[i].title + "</li>";
  }else{
    var parent = document.getElementById(boards[i].parent_board);
    if (parent){
      parent.innerHTML += "<ul><li id='" + boards[i].id + "'>" + boards[i].title + "</li></ul>";
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see all boards with "parent_board" value are automatically assigned to their parent board.

So with this Javascript function my result looks like:

- Lorem 1

  - Lorem 1-1
- Lorem 2

That's fine.

However I'm trying to archive this in `pure` Jade, but no luck. Here is my jade code:

```
each board in boards
  if board.parent_board
    ul
      li = #{board.title}
  else
    li = #{board.title}
```

This is the result:

- Lorem 1
- Lorem 2

  - Lorem 1-1

What is wrong with my Jade code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in the javascript code you are appending the second list to the correct parent element. In the jade code that you have you are merely appending it to the end of the html, therefore it will always be displayed in that particular order. The easy solution would be to put the Lorem 1-1 object after Lorem1 in the array, but that is very inefficient.

Templating engines are really only for very light logic and we're getting into the realms of complex logic without changing the data structure a little. It might be better to change your boards object to two separate objects:

```
boards = [{"id":1,"parent_board":0,"title":"Lorem 1","description":"ec40db959345153a9912"},
         {"id":2,"parent_board":0,"title":"Lorem 2","description":"bb698136a211ebb1dfedb"}];

subboards = [{"id":3,"parent_board":1,"title":"Lorem 1-1","description":"6062bc28a9f781e06417d"}];
```

So that your jade code can change to this:

```
each board in boards
  li = #{board.title}
  each subboard in subboards
    if subboard.parent_board == board.id
      ul
        li = #{subboard.title}
```

Alternatively an even better solution would be to change the boards object so that subboards are inside the parent board:

```
boards = [{"id":1,"parent_board":0,"title":"Lorem 1","description":"ec40db959345153a9912", "subboards": 
             [{"id":3,"parent_board":1,"title":"Lorem 1-1","description":"6062bc28a9f781e06417d"}]},
         {"id":2,"parent_board":0,"title":"Lorem 2","description":"bb698136a211ebb1dfedb"}];

each board in boards
  li = #{board.title}
  each subboard in board.subboards
      ul
        li = #{subboard.title}
```

JS for populating the object from flat data structure. Note that in the jade template you should probably change it so it only inserts boards with parent_board == 0 or remove the subboard objects from the main array:

```
for(var i = 0; i < boards.length; i++){

  var boardId = boards[i].id;
  var boardParent = boards[i].parent_board;

  if(boardParent !== 0){
    // Check to see if the array exists for a start
    if (!boards[boardParent].subboards) {
        // If not then create a new array
        boards[boardParent].subboards = [];
    }
    boards[boardParent].subboards.push(boards[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer Deif. Your second approach is the best in my opinion. But how would I create such object with a "subboards" key? How can I assign these child boards to their parents "subboards" key?

Comment: Well that depends on how you build your object. Is it coming from a database or something in which they all sit in one table? If they are then you would have to to extract any board that has a `parent_board !== 0` and then add it to the `subboards` array of the relevant `board` object.

Comment: Thank you very much Deif. There is still one last problem: How can I add the subboard to the "subboards array of the relevant board object"? Here is my approach (javascript): http://pastebin.com/hXqsCZvy I know this is out of scope, but I appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: I've added an extra section to my answer.